# C++ unique_ptr lvalue "use of deleted function" error

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, lvalue

```cpp
using intPtr = unique_ptr<int>;
void f(intPtr&& i) {}
```

Given a function which takes `unique_ptr&&` as input.

My goal is to store this ptr somewhere, and call this function in the future with the same ptr.

So I tried to store it in a list and implement `f` as:

```cpp
list<intPtr&&> l;

void f(intPtr&& i) {
    if(*i == 5) l.insert(std::move(i));
    else cout << *i;
}
```

However, when I tried to visit the list and pass it to function `f`,
I got `use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’`

```
void g() {
    for(auto& x : l) {
        *x += 3;
        f(std::move(x));
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    intPtr up = make_unique<int>(x);
    f(std::move(up));
    
    g();
}
```

Please help solve this error. How should I define the type of the list and how should I visit the unique_ptr&& in the list.

Comment: Why are you storing `unique_ptr&&` and not just `unique_ptr`? Rvalue references should typically be very short lived, either to force move semantics or to overload copying and moving. Putting rvalue references in a list feels like a very wrong thing to do.

Comment: Who will *own* the data in the list? The list itself? Why not simply have a container (prefer `std::vector` as the default container) of `std::unique_ptr<int>` *objects*.

Comment: And why have pointers to single `int` values? What problem is that supposed to solve? This feels very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `for (auto &x : l)`  and `f(ìntPtr i)` would be a good start...

Comment: Here ```int``` is used as an example, it is actually type T. But the problem is, I want to store the rvalue of a unique pointer somewhere, and pass it to the same function in the future.

Comment: `list<intPtr&&>` that's **W**rong with a bold capital W. You cannot have a standard container of references.

Comment: To add to comments above: it's definitely a `list<unique_ptr<T>>` you're after, rather than a `list<unique_ptr<T>&&>`. A further issue is that there is no insert method on a list that takes just the value to be inserted as an argument.

Comment: Yes I agreed that I should not use && in the list. But after I changed it to ```list<intPtr>```, I used emplace_back(move(ptr)) to insert my ptr into the list. The final result shows that the ptr is not the original one. Is there one additional construction?

Comment: Yes, there is move construction. The list stores separate fresh pointers (as it should), not references to existing pointers. Why is this a problem? unique_ptr is meant to be moved.

Comment: Alright guys, thank you for commenting.There is no problem here. I should use <unique_ptr> in list instead of &&